# Drawing 0 green balls from an Urn with non-uniform probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

An urn contains $N_1$ red balls and $N_2$ green balls. Each ball has an associated weight. Each ball is drawn (without replacement) with a probability proportional to how much its weight contributes to the urn.

What is the probability that when we draw $x$ balls, we get $x$ red balls and $0$ green balls?

> Example:  2 red balls of weight 0.3 and 0.4, and 2 green ball of
> weight 0.2 and 0.1.
>
> In first attempt, the probability to get each ball is the following: Pr(red1)=0.3, Pr(red2)=0.4, Pr(green1)=0.2,
> Pr(green2)=0.1.

---

- I think this is the multivariate Wallenius' noncentral hypergeometric distribution.
- This is a follow-up question on [Urn with non-uniform probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49114/urn-with-non-uniform-probabilities?rq=1)

Comment: Keep going: after drawing the first red ball, what is the new probability of drawing a red ball?  Multiply and repeat.

Comment: Do you mean using the Law of total probability? I think that that could be hard since each ball have a different weight and I am drawing up to 15 balls.

Comment: Use the law of conditional probability.  But are you saying the weights vary within each color of ball?  In that case, there is no hope for it: you have to compute an exponentially large polynomial.  But the formula is straightforward to write down, FWIW.

Comment: @whuber, yes, its multivariate, each ball (card at the opponent hand actually) has a different weight.  exponentially large polynomial -> this is exactly my problem since the opponent can have up to ~10 cards, that's to much to calculate.

Comment: It's too much with pencil and paper, but a computer will make short work of it.  Some useful information appears in the closely related question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20590.